# How can I best create filters based on Objects that are linked together?

Tags: c#, sql, data-structures

I have a list of Numbers that are linked to each other:

```
000-1100-00
001-1100-00
000-1205-01
001-1205-01
001-1205-00
```

and so forth..

I need a data structure or a way to be able to apply filters on the above.

For example, if the second set of number has to be filtered on 1205, then the numbers will come back as

```
001-1205-01
000-1205-01
001-1205-00
```

A secondary filter might then be applied after the first one and if I filter on the third set of number, 01, then the number returned will be:

```
001-1205-01
000-1205-01
```

Now, there might be an N number of sets so it's not only three sets. However, all numbers will have the same amount of Sets, so if the number of sets is four, the it will end up looking something like:

```
123-11-22-54
```

What options are available to me?

If I add the above as columns to a SQL database, how can I do searches without using Dynamic SQL to create filters?

If not through SQL, is there an alternative with C# and its data structures?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need dynamic SQL, but you do need to know what you are looking for.  If you want 1205 in the second position of 3, then use:

```
where numbers like '%-1205-%'
```

for the third set use either:

```
where numbers like '%-1205-%' and numbers like '%-01'
```

or

```
where numbers like '%-1205-01'
```

This about constructing the right parameter for comparison, not dynamic SQL.

In any case, the full answer to your question is likely to be regular expressions.  However, the implementation of these is quite database-specific and you don't mention what database you are using.